# Vectorize applying function on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns,  `val` and  `target`.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.uniform(-1., 1., 1000), 
                   'target': random.choices([True, False], k=1000)})
```

Target column is boolean and I want to apply the function  `score` on the dataframe for many different pair of  `lo_lim` and  `up_lim`.

```
def score(df, lo_lim, up_lim, alpha):
    df_out = df['target'].values[np.where((df['val']>up_lim) | (df['val']<lo_lim))[0]]    

    return df_out.sum()-alpha*(len(df_out)-df_out.sum())
```

This is the code using for loop over pairs of lo_lim and up_lim.

```
lo_lims = np.random.uniform(-1., -0.5, 100)
up_lims = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.0, 100)

res = []
for i in range(100):
    res.append((lo_lims[i], up_lims[i], score(df, lo_lims[i], up_lims[i], 0.5)))
```

Now, I need to truly vectorize applying the function on the dataframe and handle all pairs of lo_lim and up_lim at once and make the computation time much shorter.

Comment: Is it on purpose, that you reversed `up_lim` and `lo_lim` in terms of their definition? Currently, your code would look at everything outside that range, not inside of it.

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer: yes, it's on purpose, I'am interested in the outside range, however it does not make a difference for vectorizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your question?

```
# Create boolean mask
mask = np.logical_or(df['val'].values[:, np.newaxis] < lo_lims, df['val'].values[:, np.newaxis] > up_lims)

# Apply mask to target column
target_values = np.repeat(df['target'].values.reshape(-1, 1), lo_lims.shape[0], axis=1)

# Compare mask with target values
compare = np.logical_and(mask, target_values)

# Compute scores
scores = compare.sum(axis=0)-0.5*(mask.sum(axis=0)-compare.sum(axis=0))
results = list(zip(lo_lims, up_lims, scores))
```

The function is vectorized with a mask. I repeat the target values to match the mask shape and afterwards sum the scores along the axis.

It returns something like:

```
[(-0.7929172317631628, 0.8026151796787561, 42.5),
 (-0.6345258861041483, 0.5418223537396417, 80.5),
 (-0.6544035389514337, 0.7331799443670379, 59.5),
 (-0.9232772991482254, 0.7301427987005209, 37.5),
 (-0.5641367774783375, 0.9526164422977781, 49.0),
 ...
]
```

Comment: and where was the `mask` actually applied?

Comment: Thanks, I added the relevant line to the answer. Must've missed it while copying from my local env...

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer: Thanks for your answer. The idea of using mask is great and it reduces the time drastically, however, to solve my problem I have to change your answer a little. If you look at the output scores of your answer you see that you most of the time have -50 which is a wrong output.

Comment: @Esi, thanks, I included your adaptations into my answer to avoid confusion. If it helped you out please consider upvoting / accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If memory is an issue, an alternative solution that do not require the creation of m x n matrices, where m is the length of the dataframe and n is the length of the limits arrays, is to use `map`.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest, cycle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import random

random.seed(1)
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.uniform(-1., 1., 1000), 
                   'target': random.choices([True, False], k=1000)})
 
lo_lims = np.random.uniform(-1., -0.5, 100)
up_lims = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.0, 100)

def score(args):
    target, val, lo_lim, up_lim, alpha = args
    score = target[(val>up_lim) | (val<lo_lim)]    
    return lo_lim, up_lim, score.sum()-alpha*(len(score)-score.sum())


res = list(map(score, zip(cycle([df['target'].values]), cycle([df['val'].values]), lo_lims, up_lims, cycle([0.5]))))
```

On my machine when using `%%timeit` I get the following results:

1. Original code: 22.7 ms ± 205 µs per loop
2. Lukas' answer: 696 µs ± 15.8 µs per loop
3. My answer: 1.26 ms ± 20.4 µs per loop

However when `df` has 20000 rows then I get the following results:

1. Original code: 28.5 ms ± 263 µs per loop
2. Lukas' answer: 14.6 ms ± 73.2 µs per loop
3. My answer: 6.7 ms ± 83.8 µs per loop

Comment: I think this answer delivers the wrong output. The values between my solution and your differ heavily and your solution produces only negative values.

Comment: You are right. The function was returning the formula `score.sum()-alpha*(len(target)-score.sum())` instead of `score.sum()-alpha*(len(score)-score.sum())`. I edited my post with this fix.